# return current fragment index Fragment Pager Aapter

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I'm using a fragment Pager Adapter, but i need to know in which fragment i am, im trying to deploy different information on the fragment based on the index of it, is there a way to get its index or something that i could use to differentiate which fragment is showing?

this is what im using to instantiate my fragments:

```
private void initialisePag(Integer RSize) {
        final List<Fragment> fragments=new Vector<Fragment>();
        for(int i = 0;i<RSize;i++)
        {
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, fragment1.class.getName()));
        }

        pagerAdapter=new pagerAdapter2(this.getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);

        ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager2);
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
```

also this is my adapter :

```
public class pagerAdapter2 extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private   List<Fragment> fragments;

    public pagerAdapter2(FragmentManager fm,List<Fragment>fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments=fragments;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        return this.fragments.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `getCurrentItem()` method on the `ViewPager` to find out the position of the currently displayed fragment :

```
int index = pager.getCurrentItem();
```

Comment: that works, also i have found that you can use onSwipeListener for fragment pagers but, do u know how to know with which pager is going to work?

Comment: Use an `OnPageChangeListener`, it has utility methods that let you know what fragment is currently being displayed : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html

Comment: that listener need to be implemented in the main activity or in the adapter?

Comment: in the activity, before or after you attach the adapter to it.